# Was Casey referred to as Hunter K-5E in Loki?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki-2021

All Hunters in Loki do not remember their names and instead have a letter and number label, there is Hunter B-15, Hunter C-20, Hunter D-90 for example. On The IMDB page for Casey/Hunter K-5E. Was Casey referred to as Hunter K-5E in Loki?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I'm aware he is not referred to as Hunter K-5E on screen or even by name. The whole scene back at the TVA is only a minute or two long and he's only in a tiny portion of that so there wasn't really time to do so.

The name is shown in the credits for the episode as you can see Eugene Cordero (the actor) is noted as having played Hunter K-5E for it:

[image: Cast credits for Loki ep 6 showing Hunter K-5E]